# Solution of initial value problem using fixed point iteration

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

I have to solve ODE x'(t)=1/2(x(t))-t, x(0)
The existence of solutions of this IVP is equivalent to finding a fixed point of integral operator T:C[0,1]->C[0,1] defined by
T(x(t))=x(0)+integral[0,t][1/2(x(tau))-tau) d(tau)
I am facing the problem how to T(x(t)) in Mathematica??

Comment: Please post code as text, not images

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code instead of only picture.

Answer (score 4):

We can define your operator `T` as a functional acting on [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html):

```
T[x_] := Function[t, Evaluate[x[0] + Integrate[x[τ]/2 - τ, {τ, 0, t}]]]
```

Starting with the function $x(t)=0$ defined as a  `0&` and applying `T` three times:

```
NestList[T, 0&, 3]

(*    {0 &,
       Function[t$, -(t$^2/2)],
       Function[t$, -(t$^2/2) - t$^3/12],
       Function[t$, -(t$^2/2) - t$^3/12 - t$^4/96]}    *)
```

Define a memoizing recursion:

```
Clear[X];
X[0] = 0 &;
X[n_Integer?Positive] := X[n] = T[X[n - 1]]

X[3][t]
(*    -t^2/2 - t^3/12 - t^4/96    *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `FixedPoint` to implement the Picard iteration, both numerically and symbolically.

First, define the ODE:

```
odeFN = Function[{t, x}, x[t]/2 - t];
```

We also need to pass `FixedPoint[]` a `SameTest` that will stop the iteration after finitely many steps.  In each case, we use a 2-norm with a `PrecisionGoal` of `8` and an `AccuracyGoal` of 16.
Then we just have to define the iterative `integrate` step
$$x_{n+1}=x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(t, x_{n}) \; dt$$
in whatever way.

First, numerically:

```
(* changed \[FormalT],\[FormalX] -> $t,$x for readability *)
integrate // ClearAll;
integrate[f_, {a_, b_}, f0_ : 0] := 
  NDSolveValue[
   {$x'[$t] == f[$t], $x[a] == f0}, $x, {$t, a, b},
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, 
   StartingStepSize -> (b - a)/1024, InterpolationOrder -> All];

svn = NDSolve`ScaledVectorNorm[2, {10^-8, 10^-16}];

numIFN = FixedPoint[
   integrate[Function[t, odeFN[t, #]], {0, 1}] &,
   0 &,
   100,
   SameTest -> (MatchQ[{##}, {__InterpolatingFunction}] && 
       svn[#@"ValuesOnGrid" - #2@"ValuesOnGrid", #@"ValuesOnGrid"] < 
        1 &)];
```

Second, symbolically:

```
(* changed \[FormalT] -> $t for readability *)
integrate // ClearAll;
integrate[f_, {a_, b_}, f0_ : 0] := 
  Function[$t, 
   Evaluate[f0 + Integrate[f[$t], {$t, a, $t}]]];

exFN = FixedPoint[
   integrate[Function[t, odeFN[t, #]], {0, 1}] &,
   0 &,
   100,
   SameTest -> (Sqrt@Integrate[(#1[t] - #2[t])^2, {t, 0, 1}]/(
       10^-16 + 10^-8 Sqrt@Integrate[#2[t]^2, {t, 0, 1}]) < 1 &)];

exFN[t]
(*
-(t^2/2) - t^3/12 - t^4/96 - t^5/960 - t^6/11520 - t^7/161280 -
 t^8/2580480 - t^9/46448640 - t^10/928972800
*)
```

Tests:

```
Plot[{numIFN[t], exFN[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[numIFN[t] - exFN[t] // RealExponent, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Can be also solved with `AsymptoticDSolveValue`

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1/2 x[t] - t, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t, {t, 0, 4}]
(* -(t^2/2)-t^3/12-t^4/96 *)
```

Comment: Even `DSolve[{x'[t] == 1/2 x[t] - t, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t]` works.